# Would it be possible to create a community-built array-style radio telescope?

Tags: telescope, radio-telescope

Using off-the-shelf technology, would it be possible to create a community-built array-style radio telescope?  Much like the [Very Large Array](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Very_Large_Array) or [Square Kilometer Array](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square_Kilometre_Array) but using home grown antennae and the Internet to connect them.

If enough people got involved in such a project, could the resolution of such a telescope rival that of the above mentioned telescopes?  The area of such a telescope could potentially be measured on a continental scale.  Has anyone attempted such a project?  Is it even feasible?

Comment: I'm not talking about projects like CARMA.  I am wondering about a project that could be built by amateurs in their backyards.

Comment: What are your sensitivity requirements? What is your budget?

Comment: How much background noise is there in your community?  (overhead power lines, TV/radio/cell phone towers, etc.)